# Is this gradient inequality correct?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, inequality, scalar-fields

Let scalar field $f : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ be smooth, i.e., in $C^\infty (\mathbb{R}^n)$, and there exists $\bar{x}$ be a point on the line segment connecting $x_1$ and $x_2$. Is the following gradient inequality correct?

$$|f(x_1)-f(x_2)| \leq | \nabla f(\bar{x})| \cdot |x_1 -x_2| $$

where $| \cdot |$ denotes the Euclidean norm.

Comment: No. Just take $n=1$, take $f(x)=x^2$, and let $\overline{x}=0$.

Comment: @Michael Can one pick $\bar x$?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo : What is the meaning of your last comment?

Comment: @Michael You tell me.  I am reading a $\forall (x_1 , x_2) \exists \bar x$ there.

Comment: You want me to tell you what you mean by "can one pick $\overline{x}$"?  Only you know what you meant. I do not see a "there exists $\overline{x}$" anywhere.  In the question it says "Let $\overline{x}$ be a point..."

Comment: @Michael Yes, I edited the initial version of the question and may have distorted its initial meaning. I interpret "let $\bar{x}$ be a point" as providing information on the "type" of $\bar{x}$, i.e., roughly speaking, in which set $\bar{x}$ does live.

Comment: @Michael I was thinking along the lines of the [mean value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem).

Comment: If we can pick any $x_1, x_2, \overline{x}$ we like, with the only constraint that $\overline{x}$ is on the line segment between $x_1$ and $x_2$, we can just pick $x_1=x_2=\overline{x}$ to reduce to the trivial inequality $0\leq 0$.   The language "Let $\overline{x}$ be a point" is different from "there exists $\overline{x}$ such that."  The mean value theorem uses "there exists $\overline{x}$ such that."

Comment: @Michael Would $$\left( \forall (x_1, x_2) \in \Bbb R^n \times \Bbb R^n \right) \left( \exists t \in [0,1] \right) \left( |f(x_1)-f(x_2)| \leq | \nabla f((1-t) x_1 + t x_2) | \cdot |x_1 -x_2| \right)$$ be correct?

Comment: Thanks, I will correct my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the gradient theorem:
\begin{align}
\left|f\left(x_2\right) - f\left(x_1\right)\right| &= \left|\int_{0}^1 \left\langle \nabla f\left((1-t)x_1 + tx_2\right), x_2 - x_1\right\rangle \mathrm dt\right|\\
&\le \sup_{t\in [0,1]} \left\|\nabla f\left((1-t)x_1 + tx_2\right)\right\|\left\|x_1-x_2\right\|
\end{align}

Since $t\mapsto \left\|\nabla f\left((1-t)x_1 + tx_2\right)\right\|$ is a continuous function and $[0,1]$ is compact, you can have $t_0\in [0,1]$ such that $\left\|\nabla f\left((1-t_0)x_1 + t_0x_2\right)\right\| = \sup\limits_{t\in [0,1]} \left\|\nabla f\left((1-t)x_1 + tx_2\right)\right\|$. The statement you are looking for is obtained by having $\overline x = (1-t_0)x_1 + t_0x_2$

Comment: Thanks !!!!!!!!!